# How do I prevent undefined values from serializing to 0 for float values in .Net?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I have a rather large object class that is defined by a bunch of primitive attribute values (int, float, bool, string). I am getting the object from a client application as a json string which I deserialize into a C# .Net class so that I can save them to a SQL database. The problem I am having is the serializer is giving me a default value of 0 for float parameters which breaks my app as undefined values need to be handled differently than a value of 0. (Note: 0 values are acceptable if the user has defined them to be 0, but I can't assume that an undefined value is 0.)

I have literally hundreds of these primitive attributes, so I'm hoping there is a way to make this work globally instead of having to write custom attribute type objects.

Here's how I'm deserializing the JSON string into a C# object

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization; // Note: used to deserialize JSON objects
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

RootObject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(JSONObjectFromClient);
```

And here's my object class

```
public class SeatDefinition
{
public string DefinitionID { get; set; }
public string r3_tolType { get; set; }
public float r3_value { get; set; } // Note: this could be 0, but it shouldn't be assumed to be 0 if undefined
public bool r3_verified { get; set; }
public float r4_minus { get; set; } // same here
public float r4_plus { get; set; } // and here
public string r4_tolType { get; set; }
public float r4_value { get; set; } //etc
public bool r4_verified { get; set; }
public float r5_minus { get; set; }
public float r5_plus { get; set; }
public string r5_tolType { get; set; }
public float r5_value { get; set; }
public bool r5_verified { get; set; }
// ... 400 more such attributes
}
```

Can anyone help?

**EDIT 2016-01-05 11:38PM PST**
Turns out I'm a moron. The auto-magic of the deserializer will leave values as null if you state in the class definition that they should be nullable. All I needed to do to resolve my problem was change

```
public bool r3_verified { get; set; }
```

to

```
public bool? r3_verified { get; set; }
```

and I was left with null values for those that were not passed in as I needed.

Thank you @dbc for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: What would you want the value to be for the undefined input?

Comment: How do you recognize an uninitialized value?

Comment: Change them to `float?` (and so on) instead

Comment: if undefined than what should be the value ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most natural way to do this is to define your `float` properties as [nullables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx):

```
    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public float? r3_value { get; set; }
```

Setting [`NullValueHandling.Ignore`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_NullValueHandling.htm) prevents the property from being serialized to JSON when not present.  It's also possible to do this by setting [`JsonSerializerSettings.NullValueHandling`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings_NullValueHandling.htm) thus avoiding the need to add the attribute to each property.

Another possibility (which I don't really recommend) is to define a special "sentinal" constant value that indicates an undefined floating value; then set the attribute [`[DefaultValue(Constants.UninitializedFloat)]`](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2009/10/23/efficient-json-with-json-net-reducing-serialized-json-size) on each float to inform Json.NET of this default value; then set [`[JsonProperty(DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.IgnoreAndPopulate)]`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_DefaultValueHandling.htm) to indicate that, when the property is missing from the JSON, the default value should be automatically assigned:

```
public static class Constants
{
    public const double UninitializedFloat = float.MinValue;

    public static bool IsUninitialized(this float value)
    {
        return value == UninitializedFloat;
    }
}

public class SeatDefinition
{
    [JsonProperty(DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.IgnoreAndPopulate)]
    [DefaultValue(Constants.UninitializedFloat)]
    public float r3_value { get; set; } // Note: this could be 0, but it shouldn't be assumed to be 0 if undefined
}
```

I don't recommend this because there's a small chance your sentinal value might not round-trip if accidentally serialized and deserialized.  From the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.single%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> A value might not round-trip if a floating-point number is involved. A value is said to round-trip if an operation converts an original floating-point number to another form, an inverse operation transforms the converted form back to a floating-point number, and the final floating-point number is equal to the original floating-point number. The round trip might fail because one or more least significant digits are lost or changed in a conversion.

Thus your sentinal might get rounded slightly and appear to become an initialized value.

Answer (score -1):

You can extend `JsonConverter` to do pretty much whatever you want.

In this example, I'm returning `float.NaN` if the value received is either `null` or `undefined`:

```
public class CustomFloatConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(float);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JToken token = JToken.Load(reader);
        if (token.Type == JTokenType.Float)
        {
            return (float)token;
        }
        if (token.Type == JTokenType.String)
        {
            return float.Parse(token.ToString(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }
        if (token.Type == JTokenType.Null || token.Type == JTokenType.Undefined)
        {
            return float.NaN;
        }

        throw new JsonSerializationException("Unexpected token type: " + token.Type);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

To use your new custom converter, simply add it in JsonConvert's default settings in your app initialization/bootstrap:

```
JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    Converters = new List<JsonConverter> { new CustomFloatConverter() }
};
```

So given the following class:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public float MyValue { get; set; }
}
```

here's a complete test context with all tests passing:

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTests
{
    [TestInitialize]
    public void Setup()
    {
        JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            Converters = new List<JsonConverter> { new CustomFloatConverter() }
        };
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void UndefinedIsTreatedAsNan()
    {
        RootObject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>("{MyValue:undefined}");

        Assert.IsTrue(float.IsNaN(obj.MyValue));
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void NullIsTreatedAsNaN()
    {
        RootObject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>("{MyValue:null}");

        Assert.IsTrue(float.IsNaN(obj.MyValue));
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void NumbersAreTreatedNormally()
    {
        RootObject obj1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>("{MyValue:1.23}");
        RootObject obj2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>("{MyValue:0.0}");
        RootObject obj3 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>("{MyValue:\"1.23\"}");

        Assert.AreEqual(1.23f, obj1.MyValue);
        Assert.AreEqual(0, obj2.MyValue);
        Assert.AreEqual(1.23f, obj3.MyValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but wasn't able to make it work. Everything compiled correctly, but the resulting deserialized object still had 0.0 for the values of parameters I didn't pass in. I suspect that the Setup method didn't retain it's values due to my app being a restful web service? (maybe? I'm a little out of my depth here). It looks like simply setting the attributes to be nullable resolved my issue, but thanks very much for the thorough and thoughtful response.

Comment: @nickvans Set the settings once, in your app bootstrap. In your case since it's a WS, it's probably the global.asax.